# How to find ActiveDocument.Path and ActiveDocument.Content in VB.Net for Microsoft Word

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, add-in

I used a macro some time ago to find and replace words. Application(Microsoft Word 2010)

```
dim docPath As String
Dim myRange As Range
docPath = ActiveDocument.Path
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content

myRange.Find.Execute FindText:=findString, ReplaceWith:=replaceString,MatchWholeWord:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

i want to achieve same functionality in vb.net bacuse i am making a add-in but i cant seem to find ActiveDocument.Content to set my range of document or ActiveDocument.Path to get the path of required document.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of add-in you are building.
In a VSTO add-in, you could use **Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument** instead of **ActiveDocument**.